# scrapy----Support for Spiders with the Same Name

Tags: scrapy

KeyError: 'Spider not found: MySpiderProject/spiders/hao_kan_user_video'

I encountered a problem while developing web crawlers with Scrapy. In my project, I have multiple spiders with the same name, but they are located in different directories. When I try to run a specific spider, Scrapy cannot determine which one to run because their names are the same.
I believe that if Scrapy could support running spiders by file path, this problem could be solved. In this way, even if there are multiple spiders with the same name, as long as they are located in different directories, we can run them separately.
I hope Scrapy could consider adding this feature. This would make Scrapy more flexible in handling large projects and better meet the needs of developers.

Comment: I'm sure the Scrapy project has some way to submit suggestions.  Why are you posting here?

Comment: Or you could just  use a different name for each of the spiders.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:** Don't - It doesn't answer the question but its best to do it that way.

**Method 2:** Use the [spider's class](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process) instead of the name.

**Method 3:** Edit the source... I did it just for the challenge and I don't recommend you or anyone else to do it. But still maybe it could help someone understand the way Scrapy works a little better.

Basically scrapy loads the spiders into a dictionary so when it loads the spiders with the same name the last one in the queue is what you'll get.

```py
>>> d={}
>>> d['a'] = 1
>>> d['a'] = 2
>>> print(d)
{'a': 2}
```

So the idea is to use a list for the spiders and loop over the list. This way it will also work for both spiders with the same name, and different names.

Here are the functions (notice what class because it matters) that you need to change in each source file:

`crawler.py`:

```py
class CrawlerRunner:
    def crawl(self, crawler_or_spidercls, *args, **kwargs):
        crawler_lst = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
        c = crawler_lst[0]
        for crawler in crawler_lst:
            c = self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        return c

class CrawlerProcess(CrawlerRunner):
    def _create_crawler(self, spidercls):
        if isinstance(spidercls, str):
            spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
        init_reactor = not self._initialized_reactor
        self._initialized_reactor = True
        lst = []
        for spider in spidercls:
            lst.append(Crawler(spider, self.settings, init_reactor=init_reactor))
            init_reactor = False
        return lst
```

`spiderloader.py`:

```py
class SpiderLoader:
    def _load_spiders(self, module):
        for spcls in iter_spider_classes(module):
            self._found[spcls.name].append((module.__name__, spcls.__name__))
            self._spiders.setdefault(spcls.name, []).append(spcls)
```

Think if it's really worth doing it (hint: no).